# Display image in full browser window but only scale down if image is too large

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to display an image centered within the entire browser window. There are a few conditions though. If the image size fits within the browser's client area, display it at its original size. If the image is taller or wider than the browser client window, then scale the image down. Finally, if the user resizes the browser, the image will either scale down (if too large) or scale no larger than its original size if the browser window exceeds the image size.

I can do all this with jQuery but am wondering if it can be done using css alone?

*EDIT*:

The closest I've got is this:

https://jsfiddle.net/Deepview/o5vgo6du/

html

```
<div class="outerCont">   <img src="http://www.wonderslist.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Doutzen-Kroes-Most-Beautiful-Dutch-Woman.jpg" /> </div>
```

css:

```
.outerCont {
  position: relative;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
   max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}
```

But the image doesn't center vertically.

Comment: Use `background-size:cover`

Comment: The solution from Tobias below does that but doesn't provide what I am looking for. See the comment I made to his solution.

Comment: is the original size of the image known?

Comment: Solved the problem. See my solution below.

Answer (score 1):

Had to add the following to the outer div:

```
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Deepview/o5vgo6du/3/

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want to do? Just use `background-size:cover` and it will always fill the whole div.

```css
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
.image{
background:url('https://www.aussiespecialist.com/content/asp/en_gb/sales-resources/image-and-video-galleries/jcr:content/mainParsys/hero/image.adapt.1663.medium.jpg') no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
width:100vw;
height:100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="image"></div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that stretches the image. If the image size fits within the container and is smaller than the container, it must not be resized. It must remain at it's original size.

Comment: try 'background-size:contain'